# Existe uma maneira universal de descobrir se um período se sobrepõe pelo menos em parte a outro período?

Tags: data, matemática, datetime, independente-de-linguagem

Se eu tenho uma faixa de tempo com início e fim e outra faixa com início e fim, existe uma maneira fácil e universal que não dependa muito da linguagem, exceto pela sintaxe específico que posso aplicar para descobrir se qualquer momento desses dois períodos se chocam entre sim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que comparar o início e fim desses tempos. Vou usar JavaScript porque tem algo que pode ver funcionando aqui mesmo na resposta, mas o princípio é o mesmo em qualquer linguagem.

```js
function overlaps(x, y) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(x.fim, y.fim) - Math.max(x.inicio, y.inicio)) > 0;
}
var a = { inicio : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 10), fim : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 20) };
var b = { inicio : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 05), fim : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 15) };
var c = { inicio : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 05), fim : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 09) };
var d = { inicio : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 05), fim : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 10) };
var e = { inicio : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 20), fim : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 30) };
var f = { inicio : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 12), fim : new Date(2023, 2, 30, 10, 10, 18) };
console.log(overlaps(a, b));
console.log(overlaps(a, c));
console.log(overlaps(a, d));
console.log(overlaps(a, e));
console.log(overlaps(a, f));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Math/TimeOverlaps.js).

Note que quando está no limite do tempo não considera sobreposição. Isso poderia ser feito, talvez até configurável com parâmetro na função, bastaria comparar com `<=` em vez de `<`, mas geralmente os momentos colados não são considerados sobreposição.

Não está importando se a sobreposição é parcial ou total.